# t4mvc actionresult Converted to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get from a T4MVC ActionResult to execute the call and get the entire string from inside a static function in my EmailService class. Any help would be much appreciated

Something like this

```
static string ExecuteAction(ActionResult result)
{
     /* Code goes here */
}
```

So that I can call the function like this

```
public static class EmailService 
{    
     public static bool SendWelcomeEmail(string name, string email)
     {    
          var message = ExecuteAction(MVC.Emails.WelcomeEmail(name, email));    
          /* Other code */    
     }    
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What string should be returned?

Comment: The design and building of email templates from views

Answer (score 3):

I have done this very thing

```
 protected virtual string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
            viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        ViewData.Model = model;

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

you would implement it like this

```
string body = RenderPartialViewToString("PasswordChangedEmail");
```

the partial is just a partial view, however, there isnt any reason a full view couldnt be used.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesn't quite work because I don't have a controller context

Comment: why not?  where are you attempting to execute a controller action?

Comment: This method is more reliable than Kyle's answer. Kyle's has a dependency on WebFormView and a few other things. Doing it very similar to this method has allowed me to migrate from mvc2 to mvc3 for my rails style mailers WITHOUT changes.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use the T4MVC ActionResults to do this as they have an empty `ExecuteResult()` implementation.

I can see two obvious ways that you may approach this:

1.create an instance of the controller on which the action method lies that you wish to call and then call it. You may decide to get an instance from the ControllerFactory instead of instantiating the class directly, although if you know what type it is, I'd go with instantiating an instance from the type directly.

to get a controller from the default controller factory, you can use

```
 ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName);
```

This returns an `IController` so you'll need to cast it to the right controller type in order to call an action method. It's easier to just instantiate one directly :)

2.Use an email templating solution such as **[Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/)**, **[ActionMailer](http://geeksharp.com/2011/01/26/actionmailer-net-email-templates-for-the-mvc-crowd/)**, **[MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide)** or Kazi's **[Email Template Engine](http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/use-razor-for-email-template-outside-asp-dot-net-mvc)**. All take advantage of Razor so you can have nicely templated email messages.

Comment: Russ, you're very right about this. I really appreciate this info. How do i get an instance from the Controller Factory?

Comment: @Kyle - I've updated the answer, but I think it's better to just create one directly :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in the answer:

```
private static RequestContext RequestContext(this HttpContext context)
{
    var httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    return new RequestContext(httpContextBase, routeData);
}

private static RouteData GetRoute(this ActionResult url)
{
    var data = url.GetRouteValueDictionary();
    var route = new RouteData();
    foreach (var item in data)
        route.Values[item.Key] = item.Value;
    return route;
}

public static string ExecuteAsString(this T4MVC_ActionResult result)
{
    var controllerName = result.Controller;
    var context = HttpContext.Current.RequestContext();
    context.RouteData = result.GetRoute();
    var controller = (ControllerBase)ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(context, controllerName);
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context, controller);
    var htmlHelper = new HtmlHelper(new ViewContext(
                              controller.ControllerContext,
                              new WebFormView(controller.ControllerContext, "HACK"),
                              new ViewDataDictionary(),
                              new TempDataDictionary(),
                              new StringWriter()),
                        new ViewPage());
    return htmlHelper.Action(result).ToString();
}
```